# VueX and axios posting previous data along with data from new request

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

I have a postAsset action in my vuex store like so

```js
async postAsset({dispatch}, asset) {

  const f = await dispatch('srcToFile', asset);
  asset[0].files.fileList = f;
  const fileData = asset[0].files.fileList;
  const detailData = asset[0].detail;

  const fData = new FormData();
  fData.append('Name', asset[0].name);
  Object.keys(detailData).forEach((key) => {
    fData.append(`Detail.${key}`, detailData[key]);
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
    fData.append('Files', fileData[i]);
  }
  await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/Assets',
      data: fData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.warn(response);
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      console.warn(response);
    });
}
```

It is successfully posting to my api backend and to the database.
The issue that I am running into is that after I make the first post it posts the previous data and the new data I do not know why it is doing this. I did add await to the axios call but that just slowed it down it is still posting two times after the first and im sure if i keep posting it will continue to post the previous ones into the db again and again. Im at a loss as to what is going on so reaching out for some assistance to see if I can get this resolved.

examples of what it looks like in the db
[image]

does anyone have any advice for me so I can get this fixed? I should only be getting one item posted at a time that is the desired result. I have gone through my inputs and put in .prevent to stop them from clicking twice but I don't think it is that .. this is like it is saving the data and reposting it all at once each time I add a new record .

UPDATE:

the code that calls the action

```
populateAssets ({ dispatch }, asset) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
  assets.forEach((asset) => {
  commit('createAsset', asset);
 );
dispatch('postAsset', asset);
resolve(true);
});
    },
```

the populate assets populates a  list with a completed asset.

and asset is coming from the srcToFile method
that converts the files to a blob that I can post with

```
async srcToFile(context, asset) {
          const files = asset[0].files.fileList;
          let pmsArray = [];
          for (let f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
              var data = files[f].data;
              let name = files[f].name;
              let mimeType = files[f].type;

             await fetch(data)
                  .then(function(res) {
                      const r = res.arrayBuffer();
                      console.warn('resource ', r);
                      return r;
                  })
                  .then(function(buf) {
                      console.warn('buffer: ', [buf]);
                      let file = new File([buf], name, { type: mimeType });
                      pmsArray.push(file);
                  });
          }
         console.warn(pmsArray);
         return pmsArray;
     },
```

asset is an array from my add asset component
structure of asset

```
 name: '',
      detail: {
        category: '',
        manufacturer: '',
        model: '',
        serialNumber: '',
        purchasePlace: '',
        quantity: 1,
        acquiredDate: '',
        purchasePrice: '',
        currentValue: '',
        condition: '',
        assetLocation: '',
        retiredDate: '',
        description: ''
      },
      files: {
        fileList: []
      }
```

hope this helps out some
the whole store file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { states } from '../components/enums/enums'
import { getField, updateField } from 'vuex-map-fields'
import axios from 'axios'


Vue.use(Vuex);
const inventory = {
  namespaced: true,
  strict: true,
  state: {
    assets: {
      items: []
    },
    categories: [],
    manufacturers: [],
    assetLocations: [],
    conditions: ['New', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Poor']
  },
  getters: {
    assetItems: state => state.assets.items,
    getAssetById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.assets.items.find(i => i.id === id);
    },
    conditions: (state) => state.conditions,
    categories: (state) => state.categories,
    manufacturers: (state) => state.manufacturers,
    assetLocations: (state) => state.assetLocations
  },
  mutations: {
    createAsset (state, assets) {
        state.assets.items.push(assets);
    },
    createCategories (state, category) {
        state.categories.push(category);
    },
    createManufacturers (state, manufacturer) {
        state.manufacturers.push(manufacturer);
    },
    createLocations (state, locations) {
        state.assetLocations.push(locations);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addToCategories ({ commit }, categories) {
        commit('createCategories', categories);
    },
    addToManufacturers ({ commit }, manufacturers) {
        commit('createManufacturers', manufacturers);
    },
    addToLocations ({ commit }, locations) {
        commit('createLocations', locations);
    },
    populateAssets ({ dispatch }, asset) {
        //return new Promise((resolve) => {
//        assets.forEach((asset) => {
//          commit('createAsset', asset);
//        });
            dispatch('postAsset', asset);
        //    resolve(true);
        //});
    },
    addAsset ({ dispatch, /*getters*/ }, newAsset) {
        //let assetCount = getters.assetItems.length;
        //newAsset.id = assetCount === 0
        //    ? 1
        //    : assetCount++;
        dispatch('populateAssets', [newAsset]);
    },
     async srcToFile(context, asset) {
          const files = asset[0].files.fileList;
          let pmsArray = [];
          for (let f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
              var data = files[f].data;
              let name = files[f].name;
              let mimeType = files[f].type;

             await fetch(data)
                  .then(function(res) {
                      const r = res.arrayBuffer();
                      console.warn('resource ', r);
                      return r;
                  })
                  .then(function(buf) {
                      console.warn('buffer: ', [buf]);
                      let file = new File([buf], name, { type: mimeType });
                      pmsArray.push(file);
                  });
          }
         console.warn(pmsArray);
         return pmsArray;
     },
   async postAsset({ dispatch }, asset) {
       const f = await dispatch('srcToFile', asset);
       asset[0].files.fileList = f;
       const fileData = asset[0].files.fileList;
       const detailData = asset[0].detail;

       const fData = new FormData();
       fData.append('Name', asset[0].name);
        Object.keys(detailData).forEach((key) => {
            fData.append(`Detail.${key}`, detailData[key]);
        });
       for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
           fData.append('Files', fileData[i]);
       }
     await axios({
               method: 'post',
               url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/Assets',
               data: fData,
               headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
           })
           .then(function(response) {
               console.warn(response);
           })
           .catch(function(response) {
               console.warn(response);
           });
   }
  }
};

const maintenance = {
  state: {
    backup: []
  },
  strict: true,
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
};

const assetProcessing = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    currentAsset: {
      id: 0,
      name: '',
      detail: {
        category: '',
        manufacturer: '',
        model: '',
        serialNumber: '',
        purchasePlace: '',
        quantity: 1,
        acquiredDate: '',
        purchasePrice: '',
        currentValue: '',
        condition: '',
        assetLocation: '',
        retiredDate: '',
        description: ''
      },
      files: {
        fileList: []
      }
    },
    filePosition: -1,
    selectedItem: -1,
    state: states.view,
    isNewAsset: false
  },
  getters: {
    getField,
    getOpenAsset (state) {
      return state.currentAsset
    },
    getSelectedAsset: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => (id) => {
      if (state.isNewAsset) return state.currentAsset
      Object.assign(state.currentAsset, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rootGetters['inventory/getAssetById'](!id ? 0 : id))));
      return state.currentAsset
    },
    appState: (state) => state.state,
    getCurrentPosition (state) {
      return state.filePosition
    },
    selectedAssetId: (state) => state.selectedItem
  },
  mutations: {
    updateField,
    setAsset (state, asset) {
      Object.assign(state.currentAsset, asset)
    },
    setFiles (state, files) {
      Object.assign(state.currentAsset.files, files)
    },
    newAsset (state) {
      Object.assign(state.isNewAsset, true)
      Object.assign(state.currentAsset, {
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        detail: {
          category: '',
          manufacturer: '',
          model: '',
          serialNumber: '',
          purchasePlace: '',
          quantity: 1,
          acquiredDate: '',
          purchasePrice: '',
          currentValue: '',
          condition: '',
          assetLocation: '',
          retiredDate: '',
          description: ''
        },
        files: {
          fileList: []
        }
      })
    },
    updateSelectedItem (state, id) {
        Vue.set(state, 'selectedItem', id);
    },
    updateState (state, newState) {
        Vue.set(state, 'state', newState);
    }
  },
  actions: {}
};

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    inventory: inventory,
    maintenance: maintenance,
    assetProcessing
  }
})
```

[image: network console]

add asset is called when the user clicks the save button on the form

```
addAsset () {
      this.$store.dispatch('inventory/addAsset', this.newAsset) <--- this calls add asset
      this.$store.commit('assetProcessing/updateState', states.view);<-- this closes the window
    },
```

Comment: Could you add how you're "calling" that action?

Comment: It's impossible to debug this without knowing 1. How you're dispatching this action. 2. What `asset` is, and 3. What your server-side code does with the `multipart/form-data` request payload

Comment: If you look in your browser's _Network_ console, I suspect you'll see multiple requests which means you're dispatching this action multiple times. The code in your question is most likely irrelevant to your problem

Comment: I can post the whole store file  to see if it can be narrowed down ?

Comment: also posted my server side code as well .

Comment: `populateAssets` looks syntactically incorrect. Also, what is `aasets`? Also, how about that _Network_ console?

Comment: Added the network console to show the posting .. you see the first post Asset. then I made a second post and it posted twice., Also how is populateAssets incorrect ?  still new to all this but if it can be redone it will be

Comment: Your server-side code is superfluous to the question now and should be removed. Again, you have syntax errors in  `populateAssets`. Please provide valid code. Whatever is going on, you're calling things multiple times where you only want one call. Since the current call chain looks like `addAsset -> populateAssets -> postAsset`, what calls `addAsset` and more importantly **when**?

Comment: Removed the server side code and added the addAsset call from the vue component.

Comment: How about you attach an actual debugger and step through your code as it runs.

Comment: working on it ... Its not a real obvious problem never encounterd it before. and still not sure why it would also send the previous post data when that should have been cleared out just have to figure out what it is doing . its frustrating .

Comment: looks like the state is not clearing after the  post it just continues to stack after multiple posts. How would I clear the state after it is posted ?

Answer (score 1):

So after much debugging we found that the eventbus was firing multiple times causing the excessive posting we added

```
beforeDestroy() {
            eventBus.$off('passAssetToBeSaved');
            eventBus.$off('updateAddActionBar');
        },
```

to the AssetAdd.vue component and it eliminated the excessive posting of the asset.
I want to thank @phil for helping me out in this.